# Finding bounds for a "smooth" mapping $u : [0,T] \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ in terms of Schwartz seminorms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Let $u(t,x) : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with the following properties:

1. Partial derivatives of $u(t,x)$ with respect to $t$ up to any order are Schwartz functions of $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $t \in [0,T]$.
2. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert u(t,x) \rvert^2 dx \leq C$ for some fixed constant $C>0$ and all $t \in [0,T]$.

Then, if I regard $u : [0,T] \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ as a mapping of $t$ into the Schwartz space, is it possible to find a bound on the seminorm

\begin{equation}
\lVert u \rVert_{m} := \sup_{t \in [0,T], x \in \mathbb{R} } \Bigl \lvert (1+\lvert x \rvert^m)  u(t,x) \Bigr \rvert
\end{equation}
in terms of $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and above $C$?

If the above $\lVert u \rVert_{m}$ is not feasible, then how about the following alternative?
\begin{equation}
\lVert u \rVert'_{m}:=\sup_{t \in [0,T] } \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+\lvert x \rvert)^{2m} \lvert u(t,x) \rvert^2 dx
\end{equation}

I am trying to use Holder inequality or Young inequality to do something but cannot proceed. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you write mathematically your (1)assumption about Schwartz because the finiteness against polynomials is the definition? Did you mean it for each fixed t?

Comment: @ThomasKojar Finite against polynomials of all derivatives with respect to $x$ is my definition of Schwartz function. Yes, it is for each fixed $t$ but $u$ is jointly smooth in $t$  and $x$.

Comment: can you write carefully in your post with supremum and everything, Schwarz includes the original function also not just derivatives. Even if you just have derivatives, you can just the use Mean value theorem.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Oh, I mean derivatives up to all orders, which include the original function of course.

Comment: ok so is your issue that you just have finiteness for $$\sup_{x} |x^{m}\partial^{k}u|$$ but you want it for maybe t also?

Comment: @ThomasKojar yes, that is right. Is it possible to obtain estimates about derivatives of $u$ as well? I only have information on $L^2$ norm.

Comment: I didn't check carefully but the counterexample from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715541/is-the-supremum-of-a-continuous-function-bounded might work.